# Cappuccino Drag n Drop Examples

Tags: javascript, cappuccino, objective-j

I was wondering does any know of any source code examples or tutorials using cappuccino's drag n drop feature?

More specifically I am looking for something that show how to drop an multiple image on to the screen in any location. Something similiar to there 280 slides or mocking bird (https://gomockingbird.com/mockingbird/)

Answer (score 2):

The Scrapbook tutorial has a bit on drag and drop: [Scrapbook Tutorial Part 2](http://cappuccino.org/learn/tutorials/scrapbook-tutorial-2/#DragAndDrop).